# mmenu - How do I change the color of the hamburger icon

Tags: jquery, css, mmenu

I have searched but have found no solution to changing the color of the hamburger icon from white to anything else. I need solution specific to jquery mmenu.

Comment: This is not jquery specific you could use css and select the element and give it a color and if you really need to use jquery you $([select-item]).css({'color', 'red'})

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out where the hamburger icon is. mmenu/demo/css/demo.css.

Just need to replace the background image to anything you want. 
ex:L
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crK0J.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXYh4.png)